# Moving to the next line of data in a range

Tags: excel, vba

In the following code Range(C16:I16) will only copy that line of data. I need it to move to the next line below it because it will be the next day. And continue to do this until the end of each month. What would I need to add to accomplish this? Thanks.

```
Sub test()

Workbooks("MAY10-Key Indicator Daily Reportcopy.xls").Sheets("Input").Activate
Set c = Range("B15:B45")
For Each cell In c
    If cell.Value = Range("I5").Value Then
        Workbooks("McKinney Daily Census Template OCT 10 (11).xls").Sheets("McKinney").Range("C16:I16").Copy
        cell.Offset(0, 37).PasteSpecial
End If
    Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: its hard to understand what you are trying to do, but if you want to do something different based on the day of the month you need to reference the current system date.

Comment: @Patrick. There are two workbooks. WB1 has in Column A the dates for the month of November. WB2 also has dates for the month of November but has data in C16:I45 (covers everyday in the month of November). Range(I5) is a cell with =today()...So today is 11/02/10 and the row of data is C16:I16. Tomorrow will be 11/03/10 and I need Range(C16:I16) to move down to (C17:I17), and continue that throughout the month. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `.Offset(i-1, 0)` after the range where `i` is the day#. In addition to get the number of rows already filled in, down from a starting reference use

```
Public Function CountRows(ByRef r As Range) As Integer
    CountRows = r.Worksheet.Range(r, r.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
End Function
```

You can also use the `<range>.Resize(num_rows, num_cols)` function to create ranges of multiple cells (of variable size).

Comment: Where would I add that Public function in the code that is above?

Comment: @ jalexiou. I added the .offset and the Public function, but on my WB2, on date 11/01/10, the range for the data is C15:I15. I need for 11/02/10 for the range to automatically drop to C16:I16, but instead its just copying and pasting C15:I15 again